# Mapping multiple link tables to a nested JQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first time asking on Stack Overflow so bear with me.

I have been trying to implement an HTML page using Jquery and Javascript.  Here is a sample JSFiddle of my page: http://jsfiddle.net/R63Hz/2/.  Notice the three tables at the top have elements that map to the nested accordion structure at the bottom.  I would like to use Javascript to map the links in these tables to open the appropriate accordion section. I have tried alot of methods but I think I don't have enough knowledge to figure it out.

Here is my most recent attempt at a solution:

```
    $(this).on("click", ".linkButton", function () {
            var $tbl = $(this).closest("table");
            var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            var row = $tr.index() - 1;
            var table = $tbl.attr("id");
            if(table=="table1") {
                ("#accordion").accordion({ active: 0 });
                ("#accordion2").accordion({ active: row });
            }
            else if(table=="table2") {
                ("#accordion").accordion({ active: 1 });
                ("#accordion3").accordion({ active: row });
            }
            else if(table=="table3") {
                ("#accordion").accordion({ active: 2 });
                ("#accordion4").accordion({ active: row });
            }

        });
```

I am not sure if the 5th line is working to set up for the conditional statement.

Comment: I highly recommend creating a concise [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your issue or else the downvotes and risk of getting closed will rise. I got barley got through 2 lines of your explanation before deciding to post this comment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have edited my question as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a data value to the individual links then in the `on.click` handler create an if statement that would expand the relevant accordion section.

Your fiddle is very long/messy which is why I've not edited the Fiddle with an exact solution but I hope that the above makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have never used Jfiddle before.  I am wondering what I can do to clean it up for others?

Comment: I cleaned it up a little by moving the javascript to the appropriate section.  Going to see what I can do with your recommendation, so you mean use an if statement inside the {braces} right?

Comment: I've created a basic fiddle to give you an idea of what you want to be doing, it's pretty easy to follow and you should be able to easily implement it in your existing code: http://jsfiddle.net/n5gKS/

Comment: Ok, thanks to you I believe I have the conditional statements working.  Now I just need to figure out how to activate the nested accordion.

Comment: Is it necessary to create a condition for each entry in the table? In reality, the table is much bigger than the fiddle I posted and is being updated regularly. I would like to avoid the maintenance of creating conditions for every new method we create.

Comment: There'll be a way but without delving deeper into the code I can't really help off the top of my head. The accordion is pretty deeply nested so I don't think a standard val = 0 & val++ for h3/.div will cut it.

Comment: What do you mean by deeply nested?  Thanks so much for your help by the way I really appreciate it and if I wasn't such a SO noob I would upvote you for sure!

Comment: Ha - no worries. By deeply nested I mean the content that you're showing/hiding is in `h2 > #accordian > h3 > div`

So you'd have `.find()` the `.closest()` h2 and then traverse down to the content you want to show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found :

I renamed the linkbutton classes to linkbutton1 for the first table, linkbutton2 for the second and linkbutton3 for the third.  Then I created the conditional opening on JQuery based on that. The main thing I had screwed up was I forgot $ signs in front of the commands to open the accordion.

```
    $(this).on("click", ".linkButton", function () {
            var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            var row = $tr.index() - 1;
            $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 0 });   
            $("#accordion2").accordion({ active: row });    
        });

        $(this).on("click", ".linkButton2", function () {
            var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            var row = $tr.index() - 1;
            $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 1 });   
            $("#accordion3").accordion({ active: row });    
        });

        $(this).on("click", ".linkButton3", function () {
            var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
            var row = $tr.index() - 1;
            $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 2 });   
            $("#accordion4").accordion({ active: row });    
        });
```